# How to wrap text or insert a "new line" character into a Victory Line Chart X-Axis Label

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

When victory line chart display the x-axis labels, the labels are on one line and I would like to display the label with text-wrapping.  See the two images below to see what it is doing currently and what I would like for it to do.

**Currently What is Happening**
[image: Current Chart]

The image below is what I would like to happen. **What I would like**
[image: What I want]

I have created a function in the tickFormat to provide custom label text and that part is working.

```
<VictoryAxis fixLabelOverlap={true} tickFormat={t => this.formatLabel(t)} />

formatLabel = (t) => {
    var x = new Date(t);
    var s = x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() + (x.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + x.getDate();
    return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new line with a line break "\n"

```
formatLabel = (t) => {
  var x = new Date(t);
  var s = x.getHours() + ":" + x.getMinutes() +'\n'+ (x.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + x.getDate();
  return s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Used the tickFormat prop on VictoryAxis and it worked.